# Пару вопросов по настройке VPS для Telegram-бота на NodeJS

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, бот, vps, развертывание

Есть Telegram-бот на NodeJS. Его нужно задеплоить на VPS-сервер.

Как это сделать правильно, а именно:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы бот работал не из-под root? И надо ли? Запускаю я бота с помощью пакета pm2. Как видно, если прописать `pm2 status`, бот запускается с правами root (см. скриншот).
2. Как правильно и безопасно настроить переменные окружения? Сейчас они хранятся в файле .bash_profile пользователя root.
3. Как настроить удобный деплой обновлений для бота? Допустим, я обновил код бота и отправил изменения на GitHub. Как мне сделать так, чтобы на VPS автоматически сохранились изменения кода?
4. В какой папке должен находиться Telegram-бот?

[image: Бот запускается от root]

Answer (score 0):

Я не эксперт в области настройки и безопасности сервера, но я делал так. Если что-то не так, прошу поправить.

1. Из под root нужно создать отдельного пользователя с ограниченными правами. Например, открыть доступ только к директории /home со всеми программами, ботами, серверами и т.п. Ну и затем из-под этого пользователя все запускать. Официальная документация, как это можно сделать в ubuntu: [ссылка](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B)
2. Переменные окружения это environment variables, вы же приводите переменные оболочки. Насколько я знаю, это какие-то системные переменные, которые работают особым образом. Не буду врать - я не знаю как они работают Для хранения токенов я использовал переменные окружения. При разработке их можно задать в .env файле, а при запуске на продакшене они задаются во время запуска вместе с командой. Пример с pm2: `pm2 start index.js TG_BOT_API=bot123123123`.
3. Для автодеплоя можно использовать github actions. Тема обширная, но могу посоветовать вот [этот гайд](https://youtu.be/hevU4NdIsoU)
4. Можно и безопасно в директории home хранить. Первый пункт